# CodeBlocks Fails to find C Library after Linkingin C++ project (Windows, GNU GCC Compiler)

Tags: c++, c

I'm having trouble attaching a C library to a CodeBlocks C++ project. I have the header file and the library and I've included the header file in my code and linked the related library in the linker options. However, CodeBlocks can't find the library. The function i'm trying to access is called ShutDown.

```
'''main.cpp'''

#include "atmcd32d.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    ShutDown();
    return 0;
}
```

For reference, the header is called "atmcd32d.h" and the library is "atmcd32m.lib". The header file also should recognise the C++ project:

```
'''atmcd32d.h - header file'''

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

The error I get is:

```
ld.exe            cannot find -latmcd32m.lib
```

I'm trying to communicate with an external module - Andor Monochrometer - and the header and library files were supplied to me by Andor, so I don't think there's an error with the files.

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typically when using GCC you should not specify the `.lib` suffix of libraries. The linker will add that automatically when searching for libraries.

Comment: But, when I don't specify the library, I get an 'undefined reference' error for the ShutDown() function

Comment: When linking using the `-l` (lower-case L) flag, you only give the library base-name. This base name is without any mandated prefix or suffixes, those are part of the *file* name, not the library name. That means you should be using `-latmcd32m` to link with the `atmcd32m` library.

Comment: You should remove the `.lib` suffix, not the whole lib.

Comment: I'm really confused. When I ask the library to link to '-latmcd32m' it gives a new error saying that it cannot find '-l-latmcd32m'.

Comment: I'm sorry for being rude, but please try to think for yourself a little while...

Comment: From what you've explained to me the setup should be:

Linker Setting: atmcd32m
Filename: -latmcd32m.lib

Is this correct? I have also tried:

Linker Setting: atmcd32m
Filename: -latmcd32m

Comment: If you use the option `-latmcd32m` (as in `g++ your_source_file.cpp -latmcd32m`) and it complains that the library `atmcd32m` can't be found, have you made sure that there *is* a library named `atmcd32m` in the GCC search path? You can see the search path (and much more information) by adding the option `-v` (as in `g++ -v your_source_file.cpp -latmcd32m`). If the path where the library is installed isn't listed, then you need to add it with the `-L` option (as in `g++ your_source_file.cpp -L/path/to/directory -latmcd32m`).

Comment: I currently have all the files in the same folder. I don't know how to change the GCC search path, am I supposed to type this in CMD?

Comment: I've found a solution. I was adding the library file to local project linker settings. Instead, I added the file to the Global Compiler Linker Settings and it works now.